# Adding record to Zoho creator

Tags: c#, asp.net, zoho

Hi I am using following code to add a record to Zoho Creator form using asp.net c#.
However I receive in respose "The form has been removed from publish."

I have checked form at Zoho creator its working fine & has been published.

Please help me figure out the problem.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
    protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        var response = Http.Post("https://creator.zoho.com/saadelboury1/myfirstApp/form-perma/NEWDISTRIBUTOR/record/add/", new NameValueCollection() {
                   { "authtoken", "<KEY>" },
                   { "scope", "creatorapi" },
                   { "First_Name", "John" },
                   { "Last_Name", "Doe" },
                   { "Email", "someone22@gmail.com" },
        });
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
          Response.Write(result);
    }
    }
}

   public static class Http
  {
    public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
   {
    byte[] response = null;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
    }
    return response;
 }
```

Comment: check whether its expired or not?

Comment: @vivek that seems unlikely but I will check it.

Comment: is the page that you call correct ?

Comment: what is the response your getting??

Comment: @Aristos yes the page is correct.

Comment: @aravind in responsse I am geting "The form has been removed from publish."

Comment: @Robin the other that you must look is that the https (ssl) is correct called from your side. Maybe you have a redirect to http (non ssl)

Comment: @Aristos you are right, the url was wrong. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to find some decent documentation on the API for Zoho Creator using C#. Could you let me know about where you found it? Thanks plenty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out, the url I was calling was wrong.

The correct url format is:

https://creator.zoho.com/api/[username]/xml/[application_name]/form/[form_name]/record/add/

Answer (score 0):

Here I push the records from the school form to the student form with the help of add record task.

```
      var =  Insert into Student
[
    Name = input.Name
            Email = input.Email
            Phone = input.Phone
            Address = input. Address        
];
```

Variable holding the ID of the new record.
<<form_link_name> Link name of the field for which the value is specified.
 Value to be assigned to the field. You can directly specify a value, or you can specify an expression.